# How do I notify a row in a WPF DataGrid that one of its cells was programmatically modified?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am creating a `DataGridRadioButtonColumn` for my WPF project.  Here is what it looks like:

```
public class DataGridRadioButtonColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    private Dictionary<DataGridCell, RadioButton> _buttons = new Dictionary<DataGridCell, RadioButton>();

    public string Group { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupProperty = RadioButton.GroupNameProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(DataGridRadioButtonColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("DefaultGroup"));

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        // Only generate the buttons once, to preserve the Group.
        if (_buttons.ContainsKey(cell))
        {
            return (_buttons[cell]);
        }
        var radioButton = new RadioButton { GroupName = Group };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(radioButton, ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, Binding);
        _buttons.Add(cell, radioButton);
        return radioButton;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
       // Use the same one we generated before.
       return _buttons[cell];
    }

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var radioButton = editingElement as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton == null) return null;
        return radioButton.IsChecked;
    }
}
```

And here is an example of its use:

```
<local:DataGridRadioButtonColumn
    Width="0.33*"
    Binding="{Binding PrimaryChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Group="Group1"
    Header="PRI" />
```

Everything works as I expect it to, including that clicking on a radio button "unchecks" the one that was originally selected.  This unchecking works by virtue of the Group dependency property.

The only problem I am having is that the unchecked radio button does not register as a row edit in the grid.  Only the radio button that I clicked registers a row edit, and in order for the data to be saved correctly *both rows* (the one containing the radio button that I clicked, and the one containing the radio button that was unchecked) must be saved.

How do I tell the data row whose radio button was unchecked that it was edited, so that it properly updates the matching tuple in the DataGrid's bound collection?

Note that I implement the `IEditableObject` interface in the Model that's used in each row, so it's not as simple as just relying on `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  It really needs to trigger a `BeginEdit()` in the DataGrid Row.  I don't think that the programmatic clearing of the radio button fires `PropertyChanged` anyway, because the change is not reflected in the underlying Model object.

---

As requested, here is an MCVE (or the better part of one, anyway):

#### APP.XAML

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp11.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

#### MainWindow.XAML

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="0.7*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Header="Name" />
                <local:DataGridRadioButtonColumn
                    Width="0.3*"
                    Binding="{Binding PrimaryChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Group="Group1"
                    Header="PRI" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Model

```
using PropertyChanged; //Fody

namespace WpfApp11
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]  // PropertyChanged.Fody
    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool? PrimaryChecked
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using PropertyChanged; // Fody

namespace WpfApp11
{
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface] // PropertyChanged.Fody
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Model>
            {
                new Model {Name = "George"},
                new Model {Name = "Fred"},
                new Model {Name = "Tom"},
            };
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this code is unremarkable.

Here is where it gets interesting.  Let's place an `IEditableObject` implementation on the Model.  `IEditableObject` is recognized by the DataGrid; it allows you to provide things like change tracking and undo capability for each data row:

```
public class Model : EditableValidatableObject<Model>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? PrimaryChecked
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

#### EditableValidatableObject.cs

```
using PropertyChanged;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp11
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides an implementation of the IEditableObject and INotifyDataErrorInfo interfaces for data transfer objects.
    /// </summary><remarks>
    /// The IEditableObject interface is typically used to capture the BeginEdit, EndEdit, and CancelEdit semantics of a DataRowView.
    /// Making something an IEditableObject enables full editing and undo capabilities in a DataGrid.
    /// 
    /// The INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation uses Validation Attributes to validate the values of properties on the DTO.
    /// This information is used to indicate that a value entered by the user is invalid.
    /// 
    /// See T_Asset.cs and T_TestPoint.cs for usage examples.  
    /// </remarks>
    [AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
    public abstract class EditableValidatableObject<T> : AnnotationValidationViewModel, IEditableObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor, sets up the INotifyDataErrorInfo implementation.
        /// </summary>
        private T Cache { get; set; }

        private object CurrentModel { get { return this; } }

        public RelayCommand CancelEditCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(CancelEdit); }
        }

        private bool IsDirty
        {
            get
            {
                if (Cache == null) return false;
                foreach (var info in CurrentModel.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (!info.CanRead || !info.CanWrite)
                        continue;

                    var oldValue = info.GetValue(Cache, null);
                    var currentValue = info.GetValue(CurrentModel, null);

                    if (oldValue == null && currentValue != null)
                        return true;

                    if (oldValue != null && !oldValue.Equals(currentValue))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        #region IEditableObject Implementation
        public bool Added { get; set; }
        public bool Edited { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        public void BeginEdit()
        {
            Cache = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            var type = CurrentModel.GetType();

            //Set Properties of Cache
            foreach (var info in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (!info.CanRead || !info.CanWrite) continue;
                var oldValue = info.GetValue(CurrentModel, null);
                Cache.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).SetValue(Cache, oldValue, null);
            }

            if (!Added && !Deleted && IsDirty)
            {
                Edited = true;
            }
        }

        public virtual void EndEdit()
        {
            if (!Added && !Deleted && IsDirty)
            {
                Edited = true;
            }
            Cache = default(T);
        }

        public void CancelEdit()
        {
            if (Cache == null) return;

            foreach (var info in CurrentModel.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!info.CanRead || !info.CanWrite) continue;
                var oldValue = info.GetValue(Cache, null);
                CurrentModel.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).SetValue(CurrentModel, oldValue, null);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

`AnnotationValidationViewModel` is unremarkable; it's just an implementation of `INotifyDataErrorInfo` that uses data annotations for validation.

The critical part of the `IEditableObject` implementation above is the `BeginEdit()` method, which the data grid row uses to signal the underlying model that an edit has occurred.  This method gets called when a Radio Button is clicked, but *not when the other radio button is automatically unchecked.*

Since `BeginEdit()` never gets called on the unchecked row, the Edited property never gets set.  I rely on the Edited property to know which records I need to save back to the database.

Comment: "The matching tuple"? Could you please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? The `PrimaryChecked` source property of all items should get set in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving it some thought, I've decided to make some changes to my `DataGridRadioButtonColumn` implementation.  It now looks like this:

```
public class DataGridRadioButtonColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    private Dictionary<DataGridCell, RadioButton> _buttons = new Dictionary<DataGridCell, RadioButton>();
    private Dictionary<RadioButton, dynamic> _models = new Dictionary<RadioButton, dynamic>();

    public string Group { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupProperty = RadioButton.GroupNameProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof(DataGridRadioButtonColumn), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("Group1"));

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        if (_buttons.ContainsKey(cell))
        {
            return (_buttons[cell]);
        }
        var radioButton = new RadioButton { GroupName = Group };
        radioButton.Unchecked += RadioButton_Unchecked;

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(radioButton, ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, Binding);
        _buttons.Add(cell, radioButton);
        _models.Add(radioButton, dataItem);
        return radioButton;
    }

    private void RadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as RadioButton;
        dynamic model = _models[button];
        try
        {
            model.Edited = true;
        }
        catch { }
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
       return _buttons[cell];
    }

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
    {
        var radioButton = editingElement as RadioButton;
        if (radioButton == null) return null;
        return radioButton.IsChecked;
    }
}
```

Here's how it works.  I added a dictionary that captures the model for each of the Radio Buttons, and when a Radio Button is created, I add the model to the new dictionary and hook the `Unchecked` event on the Radio button:

```
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        if (_buttons.ContainsKey(cell))
        {
            return (_buttons[cell]);
        }
        var radioButton = new RadioButton { GroupName = Group };
        radioButton.Unchecked += RadioButton_Unchecked; // Added

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(radioButton, ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, Binding);
        _buttons.Add(cell, radioButton);
        _models.Add(radioButton, dataItem); // Added
        return radioButton;
    }
```

Then, I just set the `Edited` property in the Model when the event fires:

```
private void RadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as RadioButton;
    dynamic model = _models[button];
    try
    {
        // Notify IEditableObject implementation, if it exists.
        model.Edited = true;
    }
    catch { }
}
```